# how recursive data structure work in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

This is a recursive data structure in Haskell, how does it work?

```
data Expression
     = Var Variable
     | Num Integer
     | Plus  Expression Expression
     | Minus Expression Expression
     | Times Expression Expression
     | Div   Expression Expression

data Variable = A | B
```

`Minus (Plus (Var A)(Var B)) (VarB)` : how does this expression work?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial? e.g. [The Gentle Intro](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html#sect2.2) and [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures) both have fine sections that should help you refine this question to something a bit more... focused.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't work as it stands now. The type is called `Expersssion` (3 s's) and the recursive uses are to `Experssion` (2 s's) :-)

Comment: (Also, just a stylistic point: the word is "expression".)

Comment: @yatima2975 let's treat it as a typo, shall we? :)

Answer (score 1):

by recursively matching its sub-parts against the types of the corresponding [data constructors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Data_constructor):

```
Minus    (Plus (Var A) (Var B))    (Var B)
Minus ::      Expression   ->     Expression  -> Expression

Plus           (Var A)             (Var B)
Plus  ::      Expression   ->     Expression  -> Expression

Var               A
Var   ::       Variable                       -> Expression

Var               B
Var   ::       Variable                       -> Expression

A     ::       Variable

B     ::       Variable
```